# PHP - Strip comments and redundant whitespaces - Best practice

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing, domdocument

I'd like to strip all comments and redundant whitespaces (including line breaks) out of an HTML document via PHP.

I tried using regular expressions for this, but regular expressions seem to be not suited for things like parsing an HTML document. I also tried using DOMDocument, but it seems to also strip conditional comments for IE, which is definitely unwanted. Also, it doesn't strip line breaks nor JavaScript comments and also seems to not include the doctype.

The goal is to save the least amount of bytes needed to parse an HTML document.

My current approaches look like this:

Using **regular expressions**:

```
# Works quite well, but would also strip strings that look like comments.
$newHtml = preg_replace('/<!--\s*(?!\[\s*if\s|<\s*!\s*\[\s*endif\s*\]).*?-->/is', '', $oldHtml);

# Works, but would also strip intended whitespaces within <pre> elements
$newHtml = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $oldHtml);

# Has one major side effect: JavaScript comments with double slashes (//)
# will lead to the rest of the script being commented as well.
$newHtml = preg_replace('/\r|\n/', '', $oldHtml);
```

Using [**DOMDocument**](http://php.net/domdocument):

```
$doc   = new DOMDocument('5', 'UTF-8');
$doc->loadHTML($oldHtml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);
foreach ($xpath->query('//comment()') as $comment) {
    # Also strips conditional comments for IE... uncool.
    $comment->parentNode->removeChild($comment);
}
$newHtml  = '<!DOCTYPE html>'; # Do I really need to do this manually?
$newHtml .= $doc->saveHTML($xpath->query('//html')->item(0));
```

Comment: Best practice? Personally I'd say don't bother unless you have a really specific (and probably niche) use case to require such a thing. So, what's your use case, and is this being done on-the-fly i.e. on page load, or to e.g. cache HTML documents. Saving a few bytes here and there isn't really much of an issue nowadays.

Comment: @JonStirling Yes, I know the amount of some additional bytes isn't that much of an issue nowadays and maybe the wrong place to look for optimisations. However, I need to strip comments. And as I'm already working on such a problem, I'd also like to try solving the other (more or less unnecessary) problems. Finally, I'm kind of a perfectionist and like challenges. :) And I can't imagine that I'm the first one crossing this problem.

Comment: *Do I have to do it manually?* - if you use `$doc->saveHTML();` PHP will append `DOCTYPE` declaration. As for conditional comments, have a look at [this blog](http://davidwalsh.name/remove-html-comments-php).

Comment: @stribizhev Yes, that's what I thought and the official documentation of DOMDocument states. But it never worked for me. Whenever I call `saveHTML()` - may it be with or without providing the DOMNode -, it doesn't include the doctype...

Comment: I would use awk, piece of cake.